# fetch value from the input message (this message doesn't have any space)

Tags: xslt, substring, traversal, numeric

I have a input string like this,without any space

51=2MA011362X17=MG127AJ4015AG1A20=022=M35=U48=9CVRVC449

Here, number before =  is key and after is value. From this string I have to fetch value of 17= (basically fetch the value MG127AJ4015AG1A)

I used `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'17='), '=')"/>` which is giving me result: MG127AJ4015AG1A20, now I am stuck with removing these last 2 numeric values (20). totally confused how this an be achieved.

Final output string should be -  MG127AJ4015AG1A

Answer (score 0):

If it is the case that the number at the end will always be two digits, you put your current expression in a variable, and use substring to remove the last two characters, like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="match" select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'17='), '=')" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring($match, 1, string-length($match) - 2)"/>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply. This is not the case. number a the end could be of 1,2 or 3 digits. and length of the string after 17= is also not fixed.

Comment: How do you know that it is not `7=` you need, rather than `17=`?